# French characters in TeXworks

Tags: font-encodings, french

I'm writing a long article using TeXworks, and I realize I have used poorly chosen notation or names for several notions that appear throughout the document.

I would like to avoid spending three hours replacing each occurrence and probably going insane before I manage to finish.

So I figured I could use a basic script on powershell (on Windows 7) to do so automatically.

My script is the following:

```
powershell -Command "(gc
C:\ ...\Document.tex) -replace 'string1', 'string2'
| Out-File C:\ ...\document.tex"
```

The problem is that my text is in French, and some characters are encoded in an unsatisfying manner in my `.tex` file depending on their being unicode or not. For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  

\begin{document}

Mathématiques

\end{document}
```

is changed to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  

\begin{document}

MathÃ©matiques

\end{document}
```

The problem doesn't seem to come from the console, since I can for instance replace the 'Ã©' with an 'é' with the same type of command. (But if I do that other French symbols get transformed; I could replace all those types of symbols at the same time but I find this solution unsatisfying)
The problem is that the `.tex` file is encoded from the start.

I would like to know if there is a way to make TeXworks encode French characters as they are, or if some other editors can do that.

---

[Here](https://transfer.sh/uqmZ6/File.tex) is a link to the file (I have replaced its content with 'Mathématiques').

Comment: It appears that you are using UTF-8 encoded input so you should have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your latex file, then things should work.

Comment: Note that (assuming the characters look correct when you view the source file) texworks is not involved here, that is just the editor, you need to declare the encoding used to the TeX system so that it can typeset the correct characters which (for latex or pdflatex) means using the `inputenc` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I already have \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} in my document. The characters do look correct in my source file and in pdfs.

Comment: WinEdt might be a possible: it offers encode/de-encode on read/write for various accents.

Comment: OK since you showed no input or output have to guess.  (it is always best to include a sample code. but `Ã©` is always a sign that the multi-byte UTF-8 encoding is being interpreted as a single byte encoding such as latin1.

Comment: There is no "as they are"-encoding. 8-bit and utf8-encoding are both valid encodings. You description looks as if the encoding of the output it correct but that you don't open it with the correct encoding. But without the actual files it is difficult to check.

Comment: No we need to see the actual files. Put them in some zip and upload them somewhere. Copy & paste can change the encoding (it is nowadays quite clever and can convert in the background).

Comment: You also need to use a font that has those characters. I suggest adding the line `\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: After a fast google search: Try `-encoding utf8` at the end of your powershell command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8 (I didn't test it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I have posted a link to a version of the file. -encoding utf8 doesn't work for me but there may be a solution here, I am looking it up.

Comment: Welcome, I recommend using the code sample markdown over the blockquote markdown for LaTeX, it'll give you proper syntax highlighting but will also respect whitespace and linebreaks. Simply use the code sample button (which is the one the one next to the blockquote button that looks like {}), or use ctrl+k. Alternatively you can add four spaces at the start of each line yourself, but do you want to do that, really? :P

Comment: My editor says that the file is utf8 and the accent is ok. So check how you are opening it in texworks. What does it says at the bottom status line?

Comment: In TeXworks, did you choose the correct coding system: `Edit->Preferences->Editor->Coding->UTF-8`?